# How did Mysterio have these drones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, Mysterio

> uses drones to create illusions to fool Peter into thinking he’s a good guy and give him E.D.I.T.H. The problem is that Mysterio’s drones which he had before he got E.D.I.T.H. look the same as the E.D.I.T.H. drones. So how did he get them before he had access to E.D.I.T.H.?

Comment: He had a team of smart people at his disposal; they could have easily made those themselves.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this wasn't explicitly explained in the film and I can't find any interviews where it is mentioned. However, Beck and everyone on his team are former employees of Stark Industries and were either forced out or left for various reasons. It makes sense that some of these people would have taken some stuff with them or at least the ideas and knowledge. One of them, William Ginter Riva, was specifically called out as having worked on/created the drones.

> **Mysterio:** The integration of my illusion tech with your weaponized drones was brilliant. Powerful illusions, and your damage, worked like a charm. And this is just the beginning.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

This makes more sense when we realise that the B.A.R.F. technology is what Mysterio is utilising to create the illusions and so he must have taken it with him. Whether in knowledge form or something else. So we can easily translate his experience to William's and him taking the drones with him.

Comment: After describing how Tony named his tech BARF, Mysterio calls for a toast to "William". (Bald guy with Glasses) who he says developed the drone tech.

Comment: @NJohnny I suppose the question then becomes “why does he need EDITH at all?”

Comment: @Darren probably for the resources and the ability to hack communications

Comment: @Darren sheer number of drones? Otherwise he'd have to manufacture more, which he either can't do or would be costly?

Comment: @Darren Because EDITH might be able to unmask his illusions or stop it.